# How to put check if record already exist - spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new in spring & try to enhance my skill by creating little projects. In my new app I'd like to put uniqueness check on accountNumber, unfortunately I did not get success. I'd like to apply isPresent() method but it doesn't exist when I call it. Grateful if I get help.

Following is my Service class where I apply logics, I also mention Rep. & Ent. classes for your reference. I apply unique condition in 3rd line where find ***if ..... ***.

I've found similar question but the solution in this stack doesn't match with the way I like to do, I'd like to use JPA not JPQL.

AccountService

```
@Autowired
  private AccountRepository accountRepository;

@Transactional
  public ResponseEntity<Object> addAccount(CurrentAccount currentAccount){
    **if(currentAccount.getAccountNumber().is)**
    accountRepository.save(currentAccount);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Account Accepted");
}
```

CurrentAccount

```
public class CurrentAccount {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "account_number")
private String accountNumber;
@Column(name = "account_balance")
private Integer accountBalance;
```

AccountRepository

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<CurrentAccount, Long> {
    Optional<CurrentAccount> findByAccountNumber(String accountNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `existsBy` method of JPA, Something like this.
It returns true, if the `CurrentAccount` exists with the given account number.

```java
 boolean existsCurrentAccountByAccountNumber(String accountNo);
```

If you want to check with more than one parameter then do this.

```
boolean existsCurrentAccountByAccountNumberAndName(String accountNo, String name);
```

**Service**

```java
@Transactional
  public ResponseEntity<Object> addAccount(CurrentAccount currentAccount){
    if(accountRepository.existsCurrentAccountByAccountNumberAndName(currentAccount.getAccountNumber(), currentAccount.getName())){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); // or anything you want to do if record is already exists.
    }else{
      accountRepository.save(currentAccount);
      return ResponseEntity.ok("Account Accepted");
   }
}
```

Comment: Good, but how will this work in case if I add NAME property in future & apply condition on both properties "IF AccountNumber AND Name is present"

Comment: @Faramaz thanks, could you please elaborate bit more, how to call that method in services ?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Sorry, getting an error: java: method badRequest in class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<T> cannot be applied to given types;   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length. Are we missing constructor ?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: @Faramaz that brilliant!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my method (Spring):

```
public boolean checkAccount (String email) {            
        try {
            String SQL = "select * from Account where email=?";
            Account account = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new Object[]{email}, new AccountMapper());             
            if (account != null) {
                return true;
            }               
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;           
}
```